# Ajuda na refatoração do código jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(".img1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('box-shadow', "inset 0 0 20px black"); 
});

$(".img1").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('box-shadow', "");
});

$(".img2").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('box-shadow', "inset 0 0 20px black");  
});

$(".img2").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('box-shadow', "");
});

$(".h2").mouseenter(function(){
    $('.img2').css("box-shadow","inset 0 0 20px black");
});

$(".h2").mouseout(function(){
    $('.img2').css("box-shadow", '');
});

$(".h1").mouseenter(function(){
    $('.img1').css("box-shadow","inset 0 0 20px black");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="box first">
  <div >
    <img class="img1" />
  </div>
  <a href="t1.html"><h3 class="h1"> Aliens </h3></a>
  <div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box second">
  <div>
    <img class="img2" />
  </div>
  <a href="a2.html"><h3 class="h2"> Day of the Dead </h3></a>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="box third">
  <div>
    <img class="img3" />
  </div>
  <a href="a3.html"><h3 class="h3"> Evil dead </h3></a>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Como faço para este código ficar mais curto para dar para mais imagens sem estar a repetir sempre o mesmo.
http://omeufilme.esy.es/teste2.html aqui esta o meu site, aparece aquela borda branca a volta das imagens, como consigo tirar isso?

Comment: Podes mostrar a estrutura do teu HTML? Tenho gosto em responder mas não dá para ajudar muito sem ver o HTML e perceber o padrão/arquitetura do código.

Comment: O termo "compressar" não ficou adequado. O certo seria "reduzir redundâncias", "eliminar redundâncias".  O termo "compressar" dá uma ideia de comprimir, ou minificar o código, o que é muito diferente.

Comment: Volto a repetir que a falta de HTML cria respostas a "adivinhar" o problema.  O ideal seria colocares o HTML para teres respostas mais corretas e que optimizam o código.

Comment: na próxima duvida vou ter isso em atenção, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @JoãoPedro podias ter juntado aqui de qq maneira. A pergunta fica incompleta para todos os outros que durante anos virem esta pergunta... vou juntar daqui a pouco e na volta dou uma resposta também.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101823/aparecimento-de-border-n%C3%A3o-relatada

aqui esta um novo tópico que abri, é a continuação em que consegui resolver este problema mas apareceu outro.

Comment: @JoãoPedro juntei uma resposta nova aqui apesar de já teres outra aceite. Para responder na outra tens de explicar melhor o problema. Com uma imagem do comportamento que referes ou um exemplo no jsFiddle com imagens e o problema a aparecer. Desse modo a ajuda é mais certeira e rápida. "win win"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode utilizar uma propriedade `data-*` para armazenar o seletor da imagem, então basta apenas ter um bind para todos os elementos.

```js
var images = $("[data-img]");
images.mouseenter(function() {
  $(this.dataset.img).css('box-shadow', "inset 0 0 20px black"); 

});

images.mouseout(function(){
  $(this.dataset.img).css('box-shadow', "");
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img1" data-img=".img1" />
<img class="img2" data-img=".img2" />
<h1 class="h1" data-img=".img1" >Image 01</h1>
<h1 class="h2" data-img=".img2" >Image 02</h1>
```

Caso prefira, pode não utilizar jQuery, segue o mesmo codigo com Vanilla JavaScript. Também me parece que você está usando classes onde IDs seria o ideal, então também fiz esta modificação, por fim, no lugar de editar o style/css inline, estou adicionando/removendo uma classe para aplicar a sombra.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll("[data-img]");

var onImgMouseEnter = function (event) {
  var img = document.getElementById(event.target.dataset.img);
  img.classList.add("sombra");
};

var onImgMouseOut = function (event) {
  var img = document.getElementById(event.target.dataset.img);
  img.classList.remove("sombra");
};
    
[].forEach.call(images, function (image, indice) {  
  image.addEventListener("mouseenter", onImgMouseEnter);
  image.addEventListener("mouseout", onImgMouseOut);
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sombra {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px black
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" data-img="img1" />
<img id="img2" data-img="img2" />
<h1 id="h1" data-img="img1" >Image 01</h1>
<h1 id="h2" data-img="img2" >Image 02</h1>
```

Comment: estou a usar o primeiro código e esta a dar tudo direito mas tenho uma duvida, ele esta a adicionar uma borda branca a imagem que não pretendo. porque isso acontece e como consigo alterar isso?

Comment: Alguem poderia me esclarecer o `-1`?

Answer (score 3):

Você está utilizando mais de uma classe para fazer a mesma coisa, a classe é utilizada para pegar diversos elementos e fazer a mesma coisa ao contrario do id que é único na página. Você não precisa criar várias classes para o que você quer fazer, apenas uma. segue o exemplo: 
HTML :

```
<h2 class="elements">Titulo</h1>
<img src="img1.jpg" class="elements" >
<img src="img2.jpg" class="elements" >
```

jQuery

```
$(".elements").mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).css('box-shadow', "inset 0 0 20px black"); 
  });

$(".elements").mouseout(function(){

     $(this).css('box-shadow', "");

  });
```

Comment: Também sou a favor de uma classe só, pra representar Quem estou querendo aplicar o efeito. Senão a parada via bagunça

Answer (score 0):

Para comprimir esse código, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
function eventInElement(elEvent, elCSS, evento) {
      $(elEvent).on(evento, function() {
           elCSS = (elCSS == null) ? this : elCSS;
           if (evento == 'mouseenter') {
              $(elCSS).css("box-shadow","inset 0 0 20px black");
           } else {
              $(elCSS).css("box-shadow","");
           }
      });
}

eventInElement('.img1,.img2', null, 'mouseenter');
eventInElement('.img1,.img2', null, 'mouseout');
eventInElement('.h2', '.img2', 'mouseenter');
eventInElement('.h1', '.img1', 'mouseenter');
```

Você pode usar o o site [**Javascript Minifer**](http://javascript-minifier.com/) ou outro similar para minificar seu arquivo, aqui o exemplo do código acima:

```
function eventInElement(e,n,t){$(e).on(t,function(){n=null==n?this:n,"mouseenter"==t?$(n).css("box-shadow","inset 0 0 20px black"):$(n).css("box-shadow","")})}eventInElement(".img1,.img2",null,"mouseenter"),eventInElement(".img1,.img2",null,"mouseout"),eventInElement(".h2",".img2","mouseenter"),eventInElement(".h1",".img1","mouseenter");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que o HTML é igual á tua nova pergunta podes fazer assim, sem ter de mudar o HTML:

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter mouseout', 'img, h3', function (e) {
  var shadow = e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'inset 0 0 20px black' : '';
  $(this).closest('.box').find('img').css('box-shadow', shadow);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zg33wh7h/

Essa não é necessáriamente a maneira mais rápida, visto depender de jQuery, mas é a mais comprimida.

Porém a melhor maneira pode ser só com CSS. Menos código, mais rápido.
Nesse caso podes fazer assim escutando o mouse em todo o `.box`:

```
.box:hover img {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px black
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zg33wh7h/1/

Comment: Achei a sua resposta e a do miguel as melhores. Se jQuery é feito pra simplificar, não precisa escrever um monte de código pra fazer uma coisa simples.

Comment: Seria interessante saber porque me deram `-1`... inveja? represália? ou alguma coisa na resposta que queiram apontar para eu melhorar? :)